# ionic doesn't run for android on windows

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am beginner in Ionic, Cordova, Angular...

When I run on ionic for android (ionic run android), it can't continue to run and it shows this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I don't know what is it? how can I solved this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest you clean install Android SDK and ionic. Remove everything and go from 0

Comment: Marko - How? re-install Android SDK again? everything?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. Make sure you install everything right. Which node/npm version you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
I am using another way to deploy my app to a physical device.
1. Open the project directory you are working in CMD.
2. Connect your device via usb
3. use command `"cordova run android" if you have added the platform android earlier else add  platform using `"cordova platform add android"`
```

Comment: I got the same issues

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Android SDK and API to 18 if you haven't.